# Ubuntu 18.4 install R language 3.5

Tags: r, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to install the R language in the docker file. My Ubuntu version is 18.04 LTS

```
RUN add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/' && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9 \
    apt-get update \
    apt-get install -y r-base \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

But I am getting the below error. But it is working in my machine and not working docker file.

```
Reading package lists...
W: GPG error: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51716619E084DAB9
E: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ InRelease' is not signed.
The command '/bin/bash -c add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/' &&     apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9     apt-get update     apt-get install -y r-base     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Could anyone help to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the key before the adding the repo.

Also you need the `&&` after every command to chain them all.
I prefer to use `;` after `set -uex` for long chains so I can easily see which command output is coming from, particularly when it fails.

```
RUN set -uex; \
    apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9; \
    add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/'; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y r-base; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```